# coq auto says simple apply fails but it works manually

Tags: automation, coq

(the exercise is from Software foundations, I can give all relevant definitions but there'll be a lot of them) Consider this:

```
Goal empty_st =[ X := 1 ]=> (X ↦ 1).
debug auto.    (* (* debug auto: *)
                  * assumption. (*fail*)
                  * intro. (*fail*)
                  * simple apply E_Ass (in core). (*fail*) <- note this fails
                  * simple apply E_Skip (in core). (*fail*) *)
simple apply E_Ass. (* <- but this works *)
Qed.
```

Usually, my problems with `auto` are that it fails to find the relevant thing to apply. Here it does that flawlessly, but for some reason fails to apply it. How can I convince it to try harder?

(Yes, it's the same E_Ass. And no, unfolding doesn't help.)

Comment: This debug output is a bit of a lie. `auto` uses an internal version of `apply` that is similar to `simple apply` but not exactly the same (in terms of unification flags). So this kind of situation can happen...

Comment: @Zimmi48 Yes, I know that (I read the documentation). My question is how can I convince auto to actually do the work needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might fail because the conclusion of E_Ass does not immediately match your goal. `auto` does check this upfront and does not even try to apply a lemma if the conclusion does not directly match. Afair `fail` includes "didn't try". Even simple_apply does some conversion between the applied lemma and the goal. You can try to add a hint with a variant of E_Ass, which is converted to match the goal. What is the type of `E_Ass`?

Comment: E_Ass is one of constructors of ceval, which is the predicate behind funky `=[...]=>` notation. Yes, it doesn't match exactly, but calculating (cbn) converts one to the other. I thought that auto would calculate implicitly.

Comment: The reason auto doesn't is that it would be quite inefficient to check for every lemma if it would fit modulo conversion. But as I said, you can easily add a Hint with a variant of E_Ass - which is trivial to proof if it is just a conversion. In my experience this is more efficient than adding Hint extern tactics to massage the goal so that it fits, unless there would be too many variants to add.

Comment: Yes, adding the variant helped. Still feels like there should be a better way... :-)

Comment: It is all a question of efficiency - finding the right balance between proof power and exponential proof search time.

Besides adding more specific hints, the other option is to add normalizing goal transformations and then have a hint database which strictly works on such normalized goals. Arbitrary "trial and error" goal transformations is never a good idea.

Comment: Well, yes, but it's exactly what I thought _simple_ apply was for. And what's the point of having a total computation strategy if you're not going to normalize the things you apply hints to? :-) But nevermind, I solved my concrete problem thanks to you, and the rest can wait until I learn more about coq philosophy.

Comment: Have a look at `Require Import ZArith. Goal exists z:Z, (z<2^10)%Z. cbv.` and imagine what happens if the 10 gets larger. This might answer your question why you can't always normalize by computation before matching a hint with the goal.